why does %in% and == results differently in "filter()"?
From "USgas" library I used us_total dataset.
I wanted to plot only the New England regions' data.
I tried filter() function with "==" and "%in%".
But I found out that their results are different.
Following is my code.
library(USgas)

us_total
gas_tsibble <- us_total %>% 
  as_tsibble(index = year,
             key = state)
gas_tsibble
a <- gas_tsibble %>% 
  filter(state %in% c("Maine", "Vermont", "New Hampshire", "Massachusetts", "Coonnecticut", "Rhode Island"))

b <- gas_tsibble %>% 
  filter(state == c("Maine", "Vermont", "New Hampshire", "Massachusetts", "Coonnecticut", "Rhode Island"))

If I use %in% there are 115 rows / using == makes 19 rows
This is data frame 'a' using %in%
This is data frame 'b' using ==
I want to know the reasons that resulted different data frames.

A single value can be found in a vector of multiple values, but a single vector cannot be a vector of multiple values. That's the difference between %in% and ==.
